# автоматическое обновление данных с помощью js.coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

Пишу опять вопрос по Rails .. на этот раз по ДжаваСкрипт .. мучаюсь уже больше двух недель над этой бедой . Вот  код,который показывает историю показателей counts.js.coffee

```
year = '<%= params[:year] %>'
html_code = '<%= j render 'get_counter', :counter => @counter %>'
code = '<%= @counter.try(:code) %>'
$('#counter-' + code).html html_code
$('.counters_loader').hide()
print = $('#print_counter_' + code)
print_href.substring(0, print_href.indexOf('&year='))
print_year = '&year=' + year
if print_href.indexOf('&year=') != -1
  clean_href = print_href.substring(0, print_href.indexOf('&year='))
  print.attr('href', clean_href)
  print.attr('href', (clean_href + print_year))
else
  print.attr('href', (print_href + print_year))
$('#' + code).val(year)
```

Суть ситуации такова. Когда вносятся данные-то в окне истории они обновляются только при двух случаях 1.Когда полностью перезагрузить страницу
2. Когда изменить год с 2017 например на 2015 и обратно. Можно ли автоматически обновлять историю без переключения годов и обновления страницы?

Answer (score 0):

Решил данную проблему следующим образом. В файле который отвечает за отправку показателей

```
    html_code = '<%= j render 'set_counter', :counters => @counters %>'
  $('#counters').html html_code
  window.amount_calc()
  window.submit_loader()
  window.input_enter()
  alert 'Send done!'
```

добавил перед месенджем строчку

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

итого страница после успешной отправки показателей сама обновляется